# Can TypeScript understand which return type is valid for overloaded function with union return type?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out a way to get the following function to show an error when returning a `number`, when based on the function overload the return type should be a `string`. I know the return type of the implementation function is `string | number`, but I was hoping TypeScript could use the function overloads to tell me when if I return the wrong type by narrowing down what the return type could be. As it is here, in a longer function, it seems too easy to return the wrong type be accident.

```
function getValue(returnString: true): string;
function getValue(returnString: false): number;
function getValue(returnString: boolean): string | number {
    if (returnString) {
        return 7; // No error
    }

    return 7;
}
```

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUAUATuiEWAMpRExjIBci1+AlIwM7W3IDcAUKEiwEKdNjyESUMpS51GwXO1RtEYEAFsARqiL9B0eEjSZc+YqXJUa8xFrhwcqLGFWcbyRAB81mnUUQAbz5EUMQYYEQLaSs5ZBYgkLDkqRlEAHYeRAB6bMQAOThEXSI4IiTQgF8+CsRU8gz+aqA).

Comment: No, the overloads are for _consumers_ of the function. If you want to validate the implementation you still need _tests_.

Comment: No, that sort of checking is considered "too complex" as per [ms/TS#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235).  If you're writing overloads you just need to be careful in your implementation.  Getting equivalent type safe functionality for your example is possible but weird, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOxAdN).  Do you want to see this written up as an answer?  (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply so that I'm notified)

Comment: @jcalz Hmm, it answers the question I asked, but I think I will go for the less weird way of having two functions. It'll be easier for other devs to understand, too. Thanks, though!